# cookie issue with same domain same port but different path

Tags: cookies

I have a situation where my web application will respond with cookie `Rules=abcdefg` for each request.

**Request 1:**

`http : //hostname:8080/teja/axftyo` (for this request I am setting cookie path as below, response from server)

`Set-Cookie: Rules=HCE0F290B77137721C2F6107DD4B62F28;Path="/teja/axftyo"`

**Request 2:**

`http : //hostname:8080/teja/bcdefg`

I assume that for request 2 *Rules* cookie should not be sent, but still the browser is sending this cookie in to the server.

How can I achieve the functionality of browser sending different cookies based on the path (`/bcdefg`) rather by my application name `/teja`

Thank you.

Comment: You can't. Cookies are sent depending on the path, not on the page. It's part of the implementation of HTTP and you can't change it.

Comment: @ThoriumBR Cookies are sent depending on the path, not on the page. Can you elaboarate

Answer (score 0):

Cookie paths only work on a directory level. `/dir/a` and `/dir/b` are considered to be in the same scope for cookies.

`/dir/a/` and `/dir/b/`, on the other hand, are distinguishable, so you could consider adding trailing slashes to your URLs.

Comment: HI , i tired adding the extra slashes , but still the browser is sending the cookie . I have verified this with fiddler. This is the path which server responded " RULES=HDD55C0B2525E9F969F957E5BB9C2FEFB;  Path=/prweb/PRServlet/pbdorj4V2aBoI4ScEONLsEaxdEWiqDby*/" , Request 2 is GET /prweb/PRServlet/beEBp4uRVTogorRwSwWqbAuSszhTv2W2svU1posaO4A[*/!STANDARD HTTP/1.1, the recieved cookie for previous request is being sent to the server though the path is different

Comment: Both requests are using path */prweb/PRServlet/*. The page are different, but they are hosted on the same folder, so they share the same _Cookie Path_.

Comment: @ThoriumBR But if you observe paths after PRServlet is different right?? Should browser will not take that into account while sending cookie. If no, apart from creating a new cookie , how can i make it work with the old cookie itself? "/prweb/PRServlet/pbdorj4V2aBoI4ScEONLsEaxdEWiqDby*/ "                                                   "/prweb/PRServlet/beEBp4uRVTogorRwSwWqbAuSszhTv2W2svU1posaO4A[*/"

Comment: You can create some structures using redirection to deal with this situation, but why do you need to not send the cookies anyway? It's your server, your pages, so how sending different cookies will be a problem? Ignoring the extra cookie is way easier than to create a whole structure to avoid sending two cookies. What exactly are you building?